# Struggling to add snazzy map custom style array to custom code feature on Webflow

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm stuck, I've got this Google Maps API set up on a webflow site that works really well with the CMS and markers etc, but when trying to add the styling I just can't get it to work! If any one can advise me where the below style array from snazzy maps fits into my existing code that would be awesome!

Existing code:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize&key=******" async defer></script><script>
// Variables for Google maps
var map, mapElem, markerImg, infoWindow, marker;
var markers = [], infoWindows = [];
var mapOptions = {
  mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
  //zoom: 13,
  //scrollwheel: false,
  
};

function initialize() {
  markerImg = {
    url:'https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f58a4616a9e71d63ca059c8/5fa18680b95c219254ad0c9c_place-marker.png',
    size: new google.maps.Size(46, 57),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(23, 54),
  }
                  
  // Display a map on the page
  mapElem = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
  map = new google.maps.Map(mapElem, mapOptions);
  map.setTilt(45);
  
  

  // Loop through our array of races
  for(i = 0; i < races.length; i++) {
    var race = races[i];
  
    // Generate an infowindow content for the marker
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    infoWindow.setContent(
      '<div class="bg-race"</div>' +
      '<p>'+race.name+'<br>Next race: '+race.date+'</p>' +
      '<a href="'+race.url+'" target="_new"> Race wesbsite </a>'
    );
    infoWindows.push(infoWindow);
  
    // Place a marker on the map
    createMarker(race.lat, race.lng, i);
  }
  
  // Center the map fitting all markers on the screen
  fitToMarkers();
}

function createMarker(x, y, i) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: markerImg,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(x,y),
    title: races[i].name
  });
  marker._index = i;
  markers.push(marker);
  
  // Click event on marker
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      // Close last opened infowindow if any
      if(infoWindow) infoWindow.close();
      // Open clicked infowindow
      infoWindow = infoWindows[i];
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}

function fitToMarkers() {
  map.setZoom(13);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
   bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  map.setZoom(13); // zoom out when done so markers on the top can be seen
}


// When Webflow has loaded,
Webflow.push(function() {

    // Resize event
  $(window).resize(function() {
  
    // Do nothing if mobile
    if($(window).width() < 768) return;

    // Resize map if function is defined
    if(typeof mapResize === 'function') mapResize();
  });
  
  
  
});
</script>
```

Style from Snazzy maps:

```
[
{
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "color": "#444444"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "landscape",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "color": "#f2f2f2"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "saturation": -100
        },
        {
            "lightness": 45
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "simplified"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "transit",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "color": "#2bb0e6"
        },
        {
            "visibility": "on"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The styles array from Snazzy Maps goes in the [MapOptions.styles property](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions.styles)

> **styles** *optional* 
> **Type:**  Array *optional*
> Styles to apply to each of the default map types. Note that for satellite/hybrid and terrain modes, these styles will only apply to labels and geometry.

```
var mapOptions = {
  mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
  //zoom: 13,
  //scrollwheel: false,
  styles: [
{
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "color": "#444444"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "landscape",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "color": "#f2f2f2"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "saturation": -100
        },
        {
            "lightness": 45
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "simplified"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "transit",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "color": "#2bb0e6"
        },
        {
            "visibility": "on"
        }
    ]
}
]
  
};
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/nz14hubc/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
// Variables for Google maps
var map, mapElem, markerImg, infoWindow, marker;
var markers = [],
  infoWindows = [],
  races = [{
      lat: 40.7127753,
      lng: -74.0059728,
      url: ""
    },
    {
      lat: 40.735657,
      lng: -74.1723667,
      url: ""
    }
  ];
var mapOptions = {
  mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
  styles: [{
      "featureType": "administrative",
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#444444"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "landscape",
      "elementType": "all",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#f2f2f2"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi",
      "elementType": "all",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road",
      "elementType": "all",
      "stylers": [{
          "saturation": -100
        },
        {
          "lightness": 45
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.highway",
      "elementType": "all",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "simplified"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.arterial",
      "elementType": "labels.icon",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "transit",
      "elementType": "all",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "water",
      "elementType": "all",
      "stylers": [{
          "color": "#2bb0e6"
        },
        {
          "visibility": "on"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

function initialize() {
  markerImg = {
    url: 'https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f58a4616a9e71d63ca059c8/5fa18680b95c219254ad0c9c_place-marker.png',
    size: new google.maps.Size(46, 57),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(23, 54),
  }

  // Display a map on the page
  mapElem = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
  map = new google.maps.Map(mapElem, mapOptions);
  map.setTilt(45);



  // Loop through our array of races
  for (i = 0; i < races.length; i++) {
    var race = races[i];

    // Generate an infowindow content for the marker
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    infoWindow.setContent(
      '<div class="bg-race"</div>' +
      '<p>' + race.name + '<br>Next race: ' + race.date + '</p>' +
      '<a href="' + race.url + '" target="_new"> Race wesbsite </a>'
    );
    infoWindows.push(infoWindow);

    // Place a marker on the map
    createMarker(race.lat, race.lng, i);
  }

  // Center the map fitting all markers on the screen
  fitToMarkers();
}

function createMarker(x, y, i) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: markerImg,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(x, y),
    title: races[i].name
  });
  marker._index = i;
  markers.push(marker);

  // Click event on marker
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      // Close last opened infowindow if any
      if (infoWindow) infoWindow.close();
      // Open clicked infowindow
      infoWindow = infoWindows[i];
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}

function fitToMarkers() {
  map.setZoom(13);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  map.setZoom(13); // zoom out when done so markers on the top can be seen
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Simple Map</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initialize&libraries=&v=weekly" defer></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>

</html>
```